# MYSQL error: column cannot be null in update query

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

I have an SQL update query which is working fine.

```
Update inventory set reserved = reserved - 
CASE 
    WHEN location_id = 23 and variant_id = 40 then 2
    WHEN location_id = 13 and variant_id = 20 then 3
end 
where (location_id = 23 and variant_id = 40) or 
      (location_id = 13 and variant_id = 20);
```

The problem is I want to put a check for the update so that the value does not go below zero. I was thinking to put an extra condition in the case when statement like this

```
WHEN location_id = 13 and variant_id = 20 and reserved > 0 then 3
```

But it throws an error 'Column reserved cannot be null'. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the conditions in your `CASE` expression don't match those in your `WHERE` clause, you need an `ELSE` clause on your `CASE` expression so that when neither of the `WHEN` conditions are true you are not returning a `NULL` value, which will then cause

```
reserved - (CASE ...)
```

to be `NULL`, giving you the error you are seeing. Try this:

```
Update inventory set reserved = reserved - 
CASE 
    WHEN location_id = 23 and variant_id = 40 then 2
    WHEN location_id = 13 and variant_id = 20 and reserved > 0 then 3
    ELSE 0
end 
where (location_id = 23 and variant_id = 40) or 
      (location_id = 13 and variant_id = 20);
```

Alternately, to prevent the value going below 0 you might want to consider using a `LEAST` to prevent subtracting a value which is larger than the current `reserved` value e.g.

```
Update inventory set reserved = reserved - 
CASE 
    WHEN location_id = 23 and variant_id = 40 then LEAST(2, reserved)
    WHEN location_id = 13 and variant_id = 20 then LEAST(3, reserved)
end 
where (location_id = 23 and variant_id = 40) or 
      (location_id = 13 and variant_id = 20);
```